# pip compiling vs binaries

Tags: linux, pip, package-managers

Sometimes pip install launches a lengthy compilation process. Sometimes it does not. This was most notable with numpy, because it takes significant time to compile but is negligible time when installing binaries. I have an Ubuntu 14 machine where it always compiles numpy, and an Ubuntu 16 machine where it never compiles.

I assumed that Ubuntu 14 packages were no longer available or something. But then I launched a brand new VM with this same older OS, and pip install numpy, went super fast (no compiling). So clearly it is not simply the OS version impacting me. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a difference in the version of pip you're using. Both binary and source wheels exist in pypi so the question is which will pip choose. I found that on the same machine, pip `1.5.4` would choose the source wheel but pip `9.0.1` would choose the binary one.

Newer versions of pip (ex. `9.0.1`) have options for controlling this behaviour: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-binary

I'm guessing maybe older versions of pip don't even support binary wheels.

So try upgrading pip and then it should install without compiling.